# How to correctly give restrictions to typescript generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

I am creating this class ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GF0JQE2AGUYoUZgBzAS2DQB4AoOOAFTlAoDt9MAlYAmj56KLgE8ANHAAUAOgUoolNAC44Y8QG0AugEo4AXgB8cAK5cA1lwgB3LscamA3szhgo1AG7lgcNKS+NHTq7IZwzgC+GpisANyMbkJcAVBmCDDQMqlB4gCyKGChBq4sLDAAFtRoclBU1RRQJGQUwWjZga35hXoJLJGJLB7evnB1NAHATZ31dB0tVN1FbCVu5VU1Oa20mOFbiwVgfXADbmZowDJr-jNt6jKWwOIQAGYrupLXCnJKKuoACkoUABbYCNBisLSPZ5vVg6RwsPTqAQwMxQLiscRgYD0SHQ15seERa51VHouCVapyfZtLQ0nZaAAMOh08kUyjQvTcA1OyQCcGBSyMxPKdBg91+AEZ1FwzMCAEZTaS-ABM6lS1C4lAMJg0yklnxYEEqU1YYol+plcsVUGVyjVN08Wp1plVhopVSg+DNAQtlGlcFlCqVesoDo1zqMpllSCQjAGfPgeDQeEIzXIu0DwFs2FwBGItx2MkFhy5if8FQgZiQ+AAQsAAHLWqbC5OpgstGrnS5aABEFACvZ00kZ0l7vbLEBS8DQlerdY7msorbzac6XYuMj7xoqprFQ5HY4nCXLs6rNfrTdjK5T+fTMA3Pf7nu9++HcFHcHHvSAA)):

```
export class CascadeStrategies<
  T extends Record<any, (...args: any[]) => unknown>
> {
  private strategies: T = {} as T;

  constructor(strategyMap: T) {
    this.registerStrategies(strategyMap);
  }

  private registerStrategies(strategyMap: T) {
    this.strategies = strategyMap;
  }

  use(
    strategies: (keyof T)[],
    ...args: Parameters<T[keyof T]>
  ): ReturnType<T[keyof T]> {
    return this.strategies[strategies[0]](...args);
  }
}
```

The expected use of this class should be

```
const myMap = {
  test: (arg1: number, arg2: string) => arg1,
  otherTest: (arg1: number, arg2: string) => arg2,
  thirdTest: (arg1: number, arg2: string) => null
}
const cascadeStrats = new CascadeStrategies(myMap);
const shouldBeNumber = cascadeStrats.use(["test"], 0, "");
const shouldBeString = cascadeStrats.use(["otherTest"], 0, "");
const shouldBeNull = cascadeStrats.use(["thirdTest"], 0, "");
```

I want `T` to be an object whose entries are functions that can accept the same set of parameters and returns a `string`, so I am using `T extends Record<any, (...args: unknown[]) => string`.
With this typing, `this.strategies[strategies[0]](...args)` has type `unknown` which is incompatible with the expected `ReturnType<T[keyof T]>`.

If I change the type of `strategies` from `T` to `Record<any, any>`, `this.strategies[strategies[0]](...args)` will have the correct type and is correctly inferenced when used. Even though `strategies` is just an internal variable and does not affect DX when using the class, I was wondering what I am missing here to achieve the desired result:

- Correct inference while the user defined `strategyMap` (i.e. object whose entries are functions that accept the same set of parameters and that return `string`).
- `strategies` has not `Record<any, any>` type.
- When the user use `cascadeStrats.use` he gets correct inferences in the arguments of the function and the returned type.

Comment: • Please [edit] to either tag this question with rxjs (if the question depends on it) or [edit] your code to remove references to it so that it's a [mre] without needing to look at third party libraries. • Your expected use of the class gives multiple errors, none of which you're asking about. Could you either resolve them or make sure the question is asking about them?

Comment: (See prev comments) • Please consider what happens when `T` has more than one entry with different argument lists, and you call `use()` with a list of multiple keys. What should the accepted parameters be?  Right now your code would allow *either* of those argument lists, almost certainly leading to a runtime error. Could you [edit] to resolve that so it's not distracting?

Comment: @jcalz Strange, my get my expected use of the class working in my local environment... I will replicate it in the playground! I kept the  `Observable` type since it's the constraint I needed, but I'll abstract the problem and remove it. Reguarding the entries, they should all have the same parameters since they are all alternative strategies

Comment: But your type `T` doesn't require that they all have the same parameters.  You mean that there's a single set of parameters that works for all entries? If so then things will become a lot simpler, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NDa3zm) shows.

Comment: Oh thanks, yeah that's a problem I didn't notice. Yeah it's exactly like in your playground, but the only problem is that by doing `T extends object` I can't ensure that `T`s entries are function that returns my desired type. In a couple of hours I will be able to edit my question and my playground to be more clear, thank you for your observation!

Comment: You can write `T extends Record<keyof T, YourDesiredType>`. When you edit I'd be happy to write up an answer if it meets your needs.

Comment: @jcalz I edited the question removing unnecessary dependency and clearifying the flaws you highlighted. This also helped finding unrelated problems in my code, so I wanted to thank you for your help in analyzing the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most straightforward way to express this is to split your [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter apart into two.  You can have `A`, the parameter list type common to all the strategies, and `T`, the mapping from strategy keys to the return type of the corresponding strategy.  Given those types, then `strategies` would be of type

```
type Strategies<A extends any[], T> =
  { [K in keyof T]: (...args: A) => T[K] }
```

which is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) converting each member of `T` into a function that returns that member.

Here's how I'd chance `CascadeStrategies`:

```
class CascadeStrategies<A extends any[], T extends object> {
  private strategies!: Strategies<A, T>

  constructor(strategyMap:
    Record<string, (...args: A) => any> &
    Strategies<A, T>
  ) {
    this.registerStrategies(strategyMap);
  }

  private registerStrategies(strategyMap: Strategies<A, T>) {
    this.strategies = strategyMap;
  }

  use<K extends keyof T>(
    strategies: K[],
    ...args: A
  ) {
    return this.strategies[strategies[0]](...args); // okay
  }
}
```

That compiles without error. The important part here is what's going on inside `use()`.  Now that function is generic in `K`, a key of `T`.  The return type of `use()` is inferred `T[K]`, as desired.

Note that in order for this to work, we need TypeScript to infer both `A` and `T` when you write `new CascadeStrategies(myMap)`.  Inference can be tricky. My approach was to make the constructor parameter be of type `Record<string, (...args: A) => any> & Strategies<A, T>`.  That's an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), where each piece helps infer a different type argument.  The `Record<string, (...args: A) => any>` type allows `A` to be inferred, since it can happen before TypeScript knows anything about `T`.  And then `Strategies<A, T>` allows `T` to be inferred from the return types of the methods.  It's always safe to widen an intersection `X & Y` to one of its members `Y`, so we can dispose of the complicated intersection and just treat `strategyMap` as type `Strategies<A, T>`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const myMap = {
  test: (arg1: number, arg2: string) => arg1,
  otherTest: (arg1: number, arg2: string) => arg2,
  thirdTest: (arg1: number, arg2: string) => null
}
const cascadeStrats = new CascadeStrategies(myMap);
/*    ^? const cascadeStrats: CascadeStrategies<
    [arg1: number, arg2: string], 
    { test: number; otherTest: string; thirdTest: null; }
    >
*/
const shouldBeNumber = cascadeStrats.use(["test"], 0, "");
//    ^? const shouldBeNumber: number
const shouldBeString = cascadeStrats.use(["otherTest"], 0, "");
//    ^? const shouldBeString: string
const shouldBeNull = cascadeStrats.use(["thirdTest"], 0, "");
//    ^? const shouldBeNull: null
const shouldBeStringOrNumber = cascadeStrats.use(["test", "otherTest"], 0, "")
//    ^? const shouldBeStringOrNumber: string | number

cascadeStrats.use(["test"], "oops", "abc"); // error!
// -----------------------> ~~~~~~
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

Looks good. `T` is inferred properly, so that `shouldBeXXX` are all of the expected types, and `A` is also inferred properly, so that the compiler notices if you pass in the wrong parameter type (as shown in the last line above).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBDYEDmBLCBnAPAQSggA8UA7AEyykVJAG0BdAGigBUA+KAXgCgooA3lDoBpKOlJQA1hBAB7AGZsGALigAKAHTbE8VFjV4AlN06tRDKAF8ePAMYAbRFioBhZ3cTkIcJCgzY+IQkEBRUNPTMbMFklFByAEYAVhB2wJwCfFBg8OgAbsjQWAiFAVgAhGq+pZi4eCwctvx2cqTF8ACuaXLw6u2lIACyiGAqWfwASqk95DjtEqgsWjp6BlDGptS0nABk47Al-rX4DexZJpn8-MAAFuhYmvBo9yjw1UfYfYdoQyNGANxZGxZHL5QpQJ4YYoQN7fMpfPw-YajA6IsonNjsC77W73TT9D5ULhQAlIkaA-jA-gdLAQHBiYixKgyeRKDjqfakspqESMJj7bSaXT6QznQT7J7ADrwSS4h5c2p0BXYOgABgYDGWQtWAKBPGB9laxSgAFtfmBuOLrthgGp1MKAIxqUgdE0JGEsYUAJjU81IqBMXE4jv5-DktxhrBtdsdztd7vgnr0PpJCAWgeDydDUFx8HIUeKMb0TqgLrdHuoyd9af9GdLHQcDn1hrawCgniwnm87yJpYgAHcoO5O14fHDauozcjdQB6GdXKAAPQA-C3jVgbnIG+QAEIQABy8Zhlo7XbHfgeNIg6joACIUMVb1FVSxb7fZ-Oriu122N1uHLu54LCeHijj2mhXjet7hjckY2k+LAvlAb4fgu34tK2JKbtue6Ho2IEjt2hyXrSUG5vm8HPq+76AnOaGrhh67YQBe6+AsADy8CHuW8AEWe4GQXeD7ALer4wXBj5Uch748HRX6rvYoFEReEGkUJlFiXIYBYKJyGIAkdg0VAdEwvAPTlLJ84ALQ2bZdn2Q5NmcAAfq5bmWeseiuqEbaKDm4DQAA5H6qCBeIVCkOG1AuOgqCkPpDjQMAcjZLoiAmhArzxEooCQFAgVlgmgWaEAA)